# android studio error: sdk tools directory is missing

Tags: android-studio, sdk

I installed android studio 3.0.1 on a clear windows 10.

after install ask me to choose sdk directory location and suggested to me a default path:

```
C:\Users\saeid\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

and I don't change that path and clicked on next button and in the next page show me this error:

```
Nothing to do! 
SDK tools directory is missing
```

now everytime I run android studio ask me to specify the sdk path. and I even reinstalled it but my problem didn't solve.

exactly what I must do ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've checked alot of similar questions on stackoverflow and nothing helps. I don't know about Iran but I'm under google sanctions. I just used vpn at the same situation and 'Android Studio - SDK manager' shows me available package so I'm installing now. 
P.S. I using TouchVPN on Win10
P.S.S so packages were not installed previously as it trying to download from *.google.com and this is not available due to code 403.

Comment: I used an strong vpn and then android studio automatically downloaded needed sdks and my problem solved . **Death to google's sanctions**